# Converting a valarray to a vector without copying

Tags: c++, vector, valarray

I have a really large valarray that I need to convert to a vector because a library I'm using only takes a vector as input. I'm wondering if it's possible to convert from valarray to vector without copying. Here's what I have:

```
#include <vector>
#include <valarray>

int main() {
    std::valarray<double> va{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} };

    //Error: cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<eT,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
    //std::vector<double> v1{ std::begin(va), va.size() };

    //Error: cannot convert from 'std::valarray<double>' to 'std::vector<eT,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
    //std::vector<double> v2{ std::move(va) };

    // Works but I'm not sure if it's copying
    std::vector<double> v3;
    v3.assign(std::begin(va), std::end(va));
}
```

The documentation on [assign](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/) says that the function "assigns new contents to the vector, replacing its current contents, and modifying its size accordingly.". This sounds to me like it copies. Is there a way to do it without copying?

Comment: With `std::valarray` and `std::vector` I'm fairly certain it's impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I am afraid it is not possible to convert a `valarray` to a `vector` without copying.

Your options are:

1. Convert your existing codebase to use `vector`, and use [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) to retain most of the benefits of `valarray`.
2. Convert the library to use `valarray`.
3. Copy.

I would start with option 3 and just copy.

Comment: *"I would start with option 3 and just copy."* Good advice, it's not too slow until measurement proves it is.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It would've been a nice function to have. Thanks for your help.